# Download file using url doestwork JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need to start a download by pressing a button, I tried use the follow code, but it DOESN'T start the download, just open a new tab in browser and show the content. I am doing wrong?

The dataurl is exactly something like : http://localhost:8000/storage/shipment/b61ffc10-6798-4b94-ba91-daec6efbbdfdShipment2020-10-05.txt

```
  download: function(name, dataurl) {
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("download", name+'.txt');
      link.setAttribute("target", "_blank")
      link.href = dataurl;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    }
```

I also tried convert the url to Blob

```
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", filename);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    },
```

That way, it trigged the download, but the content was the url, not the file itself.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to download a content from your server try this one , its so simle...

```
<a href="http://localhost:8000/storage/shipment/b61ffc10-6798-4b94-ba91-daec6efbbdfdShipment2020-10-05.txt" download="filename-here"> Click here to Download </a>
```

Added `Download` Atribute in `<a>` tag , when clicking on this link, the file will download as `filename-here.txt`

Comment: If you look at the question OP is already setting the download attribute programatically

Comment: I've alreay tried it, but the download atributte doesn't work. I had to build a new url to make it work, I don't know why this happened